# Multiple DropDownListFor bound to same model property generate same ID and name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

Consider the following model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<MyViewModelGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModelGroup
{
    public List<MyViewModelGroupItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModelGroupItem
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> QuantityOptions { get; set; }

    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

I need to display multiple forms on a single web page each containing dropdown lists for the MyViewModelGroupItem->Quantity property.

In order to do this, I have a view which contain a loop to traverse the MyViewModel->Groups relationship using a foreach loop contining @Html.Partial("Groups", group) and a view to traverse the MyViewModelGroup->Items relationship using @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Items). Note: I believe MVC cannot use multiple nested EditorFor, hence the use of Partial. **THIS WAS AN INCORRECT ASSUMPTION FOR MVC 4**

All of this works OK and the EditorFor contains the code to display the forms and lists:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.MyViewModelGroupItem

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyView", "My", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="item">
        <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Quantity, Model.QuantityOptions, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })</div>
    </div>
}
```

The problem is, that after postback, all of the dropdowns get set to the new user selected value as they all have the same name:

```html
<select id="Items_0__Quantity" name="Items[0].Quantity"...>
```

Also, the model which is posted back to the controller correctly has the user value set in 'Quantity', but the ID is null, so I cannot work out which item has been set? If I try to add a hidden field with the ID data, it also always returns as null.

**UPDATE**
I have changed the code to use nested EditorFor and it now correctly names the items:

```
<select id="Groups_0__Items_0__Quantity" name="Groups[0].Items[0].Quantity"...>
<select id="Groups_1__Items_0__Quantity" name="Groups[1].Items[0].Quantity"...>
```

I have also move everything to a single form and the postback receives the whole object model. The ID was still null, so I added a hidden field and now the ID gets set into the model OK:

```
@Html.Hidden("ID", Model.ID)
```

The idea behind using multiple forms was so that I knew which item had changed.

I could just persist the whole model in postback, but is there anyway to know which value changed?

Comment: you said those fields are on different forms, so theres no problem with those fields having the same name

Comment: There is no any problem in nesting EditorFor helpers. Actually your issue occurs because you are using Partial instead of using EditorTemplate

Comment: MVC **can** use multiple nested `EditorFor()` and it is the way you need to do it. But you have said you need to _display multiple forms_. Are you trying to create a form in each iteration of a loop? - it which you need to show more of your view

Comment: Thanks for the response, please see updated question.

Comment: There are numerous ways you could handle this. (a) In the POST method, get the original and compare it. (b) Include a property for (say) `IsDirty` and use javascript to update a hidden input (c) Include a property for (say)  `OriginalQuantity` and compare it with `Quantity` in the POST method. You have now changed the question so much your unlikely to get an answer.